# apply function to dataframe column having lat-long and remove rows for invalid lat-long

Tags: python, pandas, location

I have a datafrme **df1** like below: lat-long can be duplicate

```
miles uid lat_long
12    235  (45,67)
13    234  (41.09,67)
14    233  (34,55)
15    236  (12.23,65.78)
16    239  (27,34)
```

I want remove the entry from **df1** if the lat_long value is invalid.I am doing this like below but taking too much time.

```
all_lat_long = df1["lat_long"].tolist(). #list of tuples
def lat_long_check(each_coordnts):
        match = re.match('^\((?P<lat>-?\d*(.\d+)),(?P<long>-?\d*(.\d+))\)$',
                         str(each_coordnts))   #find invalid lat-long
        if match is None:
            idx = df1[df1['lat_long'] == each_coordnts].index
            df1.drop(idx,inplace=True)

for each_coordnts in  all_lat_long:
    lat_long_check(each_coordnts)
```

Is there any efficient way to do this for 1M records? Once wrong lat-long entries are removed, I want populate two new columns at the end of df1-**"Latitude"** and **"Longitude"** and populate corresponding values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would proceed as follows:

1. Define a function `validate_lat_long` that returns a tuple of floats if the latitude/longitude values are correct. I assume this has to do with checking that the values are within expected intervals (-90 to 90 for latitude, etc). The function should return `np.nan` if the values are not correct.
2. Create a new column with correct values as follows:

```py
df1["validated_lat_long"] = df1["lat_long"].apply(validate_lat_long)
```

3. Finally, in order to remove invalid values, use `dropna` on the new column and possibly make a new dataframe if you need to preserve the previous work:

```py
new_df = df1.dropna(subset=["validated_lat_long"])
```

Your code is most probably slow because it iterates on dataframe rows. Applying a function with `df.apply()` should speed things up reasonably. Also I hope you can check floats instead of searching for a regex.